# python read and split 2GB text file take 28GB of RAM?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a 2GB text file and split it line and store in a list. The problem is this process takes out about 28GB of RAM and i don't know how to fix it! Please help!

```
corpus = []

with open('path', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file:
        corpus.append(line.strip().split())
```

Comment: Well, you are storing all the read lines in an array, that is your loading the entire file, plus you have to consider that a line extracted from the file becomes a string object and naturally this takes up more space.

Comment: So there is nothing i can do??? I have to save all the text to list :(

Comment: What you would do on every line should be done in the for loop